# Issue with javascript retrieve form data for url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am kind of new to javascript however I have created a submit form that I want to redirect me to a url based on form input. Here is my current code...

The issue I'm running into however is that the form is sending me the initial value rather than the updated form value (It is using "whatevs" no matter what).

HTML

```
     <form id="Search-Form" onClick="genURL()"><label>Value: </label> 
     <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter Value"></input>                           
     <div id="search-buttons">
         <input id="searchSubmit" value="whatevs" type="submit"  tabindex="1" />
     </div>
     </form>
```

Javascript

```
    function genURL() {
        var searchSubmit = document.getElementById("searchSubmit").value;
        window.location = "randomsite/view" + searchSubmit;
    }
```

Comment: `onsubmit` instead of `onClick`  
`document.getElementById("search").value` instead of `document.getElementById("searchSubmit").value`

Answer (score 1):

Add `return` and use `onsubmit`:

```
 <form id="Search-Form" onsubmit="return genURL()"><label>Value: </label> 
 <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter Value"></input>                           
 <div id="search-buttons">
     <input id="searchSubmit" value="whatevs" type="submit"  tabindex="1" />
 </div>
 </form>
```

Revise function like so:

```
function genURL()
{
    location.href = "randomsite/view" + document.getElementById("search").value;
    return false;
}
```

If you were to use onclick, it would go on the button, not the form.